# How to get rid of empty cells in EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm trying to add row to a list object from excel file with empty cells. for some reason getting reference object is not set to instance return null. not sure what could be possible solution for this.

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
for(int row = 2; row <= rowcount; row++)
{

  list.Add(new Insured
  {
      item1 = worksheet.Cells [row, 1].Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim(),
      item2 = worksheet.Cells [row, 2].Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim(), //<cell is empty

  });
}
```

Comment: `.ToString()` can't be called if the cell's value is null, since you are talking about empty cells you have to assume that the Value will be NULL and not an empty string ""

Comment: use `Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells [row, 1].Value)`; which returns an empty string on a null object as you can see here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/20698b4e77008a86f08c2870e2ae7859142978f5/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Convert.cs#L1942